# Access to byte stream while deserializing JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, sha

I've been trying to find a mechanism to provide access to the raw json while deserialising a field in json.net. My class is something like this:

```
public class Message {
    public Signature Signature { get; set; }
    public string Payload { get; set; }
}
```

This currently gets serialised to:

```
{
  "$type": "SignedMessage",
  "Signature": {
    // Signature details here
  },
  "Payload": "{\"$type\": \"Foo\", \"value\":\"Bar\" }"
}
```

The payload itself is json that has currently must be produced in a prior serialisation step, and conversely has to be deserialised in a following seperate step, this also means the json produced isn't particularly clean since it gets encapsulated within the outer wrapper. The current arrangement allows me to hash the Payload so i can either produce a signature or validate an existing one.

I'd like to be able to make Message generic:

```
public class Message<T> {
    public Signature Signature { get; set; }
    public <T> Payload { get; set; }
}
```

Which I can certainly do but then Payload is automatically deserialized (which is good) and I miss my opportunity to calculate a hash for signature verification (which is bad). It leaves me with two options:

- Add conditions to T so it implements some interface aiding hash calculation.
- While deserializing perform a hash on the raw json of Payload.

The first option sounded OK until i realized that i'd have to the method on EVERY class being serialized and then it sounded terrible.

The deserialisation calculation sounds a lot nicer and makes things more flexible for how and where that hash gets calculated.

The problem is thus far I can't seem to find anything allowing me access to the raw json within the json.net conversion process. Does json.net even feature that capability?

For the most part I'd like to minimize the custom code required for deserialisation, though I have written a few minimal effort converters to make the json neater.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into using a `CustomCreationConverter` to read the JSON prior to deserialization?

Comment: So how signature is calculated? Is it just HASH(payloadJsonString), or calculates from different values inside payload?

Comment: So is the `string Payload` actually a nested double-serialized JSON string literal?

Comment: Yes Payload is a json string that gets serialised in another step (which hopefully I can also optimise with this change). Currently the hash is running over the raw json string in Payload. I think this is the best method as it permits a 3rd party code bases to calculate the hash in the same way.

Comment: Also yes I have looked at JsonConverters (using a few) and creation converters. I haven't seen thus far anything in the API that would give you the raw json string unfortunately.

Comment: You can have `string` payload as a separate private property, which will be serialized\deserialized by JSON.NET, and have `T` payload as a public property. When set - you will serialize it to private string. When get - you will deserialize it from private string (and cache).

Comment: Not quite what I'm after but I can see it achieving the result. 

Given that I'm not sure its possible to do what I want with json.net you might as well write it up as an answer, unless someone has a better one you'd get it.